# Java Progress Bar is Grey

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I implemented an indeterminate java progress bar in my program but for some reason the progress bar is grey instead of blue. Any ideas why this is happening?

[image: Grey ProgressBar]

This is how the progress bar looks; it is supposed to have moving blue lines shown below instead of the stationary grey ones as shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Please give more detail. Code examples perhaps?

Comment: Maybe like me it's just getting old. There's nothing wrong with grey, nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the JProgressBar is disabled. When working with a GUI Editor, search for the option `enabled` and make sure it is set to `true`.

You can do it manually as well by calling:

```
progressbar.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are talking about a awt/swing application. The progress bar color, along with every other GUI element, is regulated by the Look & Feel of the application. Swing/awt have standardized look and feels, but also some that are heavily platform-dependent. For more precise information, please provide a screenshot of your progress bar and also of the one that you think your bar should look like.

For information how to set the look & feel, look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

EDIT:
Can you provide the code of your app where you define the progress bar? I assume it is a JProgressBar? Also, what OS do you use?

EDIT EDIT:
The progress bar you created can have its look and feel changed.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingJProgressBarLookandFeel.htm

Experiment with the mentioned properties like that:

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.blue);
```

Until you achieve a result that is suitable to you. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not using look and feel; It looks fine in the sample program I downloaded (ProgressBarDemo2) but in my application it is not working

Comment: By not using look and feel, you mean you are using 'Metal', or as it is also known 'CrossPlatformLookAndFeel'. However, the program you have downloaded may use a different look and feel. In order to pinpoint the problem you might want to provide OS and screenshots and maybe you can provide some screenshots so we can which L&F each app uses.

Comment: They both seem to be using the default look & feel